# Axios request to Gmail API unauthorised error?

Tags: javascript, axios, gmail

I have tried to send, with Google API and Axios, a new email:

```
  async SendMail (req, res) {
        try {
      const email = `From: ${req.body.sender}\r\n` + `To: ${req.body.receiver}\r\n` + `Subject: ${req.body.subject}\r\n\r\n` + req.body.message
      const response = await axios.post(`https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/${req.body.userId}/messages/send`, email, {headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${req.body.token}`, 'content-type': 'message/rfc822'}})
      res.status(200).send({data: response.data, status: 'ok'})
    } catch(err) {
      console.log('error => ', err)
      res.status(404).send({
        error: 'Error for the recuperation of Google info'
      })
    }
  }
```

It tells me I am unauthorised but I have added the correct scopes.

```
error: {
 response: {
  status: 401,
  statusText: 'Forbidden',
  ...
 }
}
```

The accessToken is working I have done a call with a get with it and it worked pretty fine.

This is my scope: https://mail.google.com/

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I could confirm that the modified script works with the access token including the scope of only `https://mail.google.com/`. But, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. So I think that my answer is not useful for your situation. So I have to delete my answer because I don't want to confuse other users. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Your response was usefull and it had help me @Tanaike I just edited the new calling I just have to find why I am with forbiden

Comment: Thank you for replying. But, unfortunately, I couldn't resolve your issue because of my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. I would like to study more and more.

Comment: @Tanaike I solved it before but you were right and I am just an idiot who forgot to pass a userId to this function :)